# Ajax response returns html code instead of user data

Tags: plugins, ajax, dashboard

Ok, so I ran into an issue where I had disabled access to the default WP dashboard for specific user roles; however, this also inhibits ajax calls to the ajax-admin.php endpoint, which is necessary for what I am trying to do. If anyone knows a useful workaround for this particular scenario that does not require a complete redesign, I would appreciate it, as I do not really see any information on this particular issue. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace your call to wp_ajax for a custom REST endpoint.

This should be useful: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Cool thanks I was actually wondering about how to create customized REST routes with wordpress. This should essentially bypass the wp_admin privilege settings without having to worry excessively about CRSF filters (since this endpoint would only be used for accessing low priority data).